# Possessive of Quoted Song Title in Quotes

Tags: punctuation, possessives, quotation-marks, titles

Without recasting the following sentence, is the possessive of the quoted song title correctly punctuated as exampled? I am aware that it can be reworded to avoid the problem, but I wanted to know whether 'punctuation-wise' this is correct. Song titles receive quotes; album titles are italicized.

> “Hey Jude” ’s popularity reached unprecedented heights in 1968.

Comment: Though seems like off-topic, this is a good question. However, I'm quite sure no canonical answer exists.

Comment: As we can't even agree on a canon listing a rule for 'wordness', there seems little likelihood that we'll agree on punctuation and grammar. I bet we can't even agree on who 'we' might be.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quoted Possessives Ending in "s"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/542417/quoted-possessives-ending-in-s)

Answer (score 3):

Song titles can be italicised, and that would make this far less awkward.

> *Hey Jude*’s popularity reached unprecedented heights in 1968.

Better still to reword it to avoid the possessive altogether, though.

Comment: No style guide shows that individual song titles can be italicized—only album titles can be.

Comment: A style guide is simply opinion bound into a book. There is nothing stopping song titles being set in italics.

Comment: Both options have been ruled out in advanced by the OP.

Comment: At http://www.stlcc.edu/Student_Resources/Academic_Resources/Writing_Resources/Grammar_Handouts/italics_vs__quotation_marks.pdf are the instructions: TITLES/NAMES TO BE PUT IN ITALICS:  Books: _To Kill a Mockingbird_ ...
Long Poems: _The Odyssey_  ...
Operas/Musical Pieces ... _Rhapsody in Blue_ ...
TITLES/NAMES TO BE PUT IN QUOTATION MARKS: 
 ...
Short Stories “Why I Live at the P.O.” ...
Songs “Can’t Buy Me Love” ...  Who decides when a story gets beyond short status, or a poem becomes long, or when a song isn't a 'musical piece'? This all smacks of arbitrarily enforced pseudorules.

Comment: Quite. Song titles **can** be italicised, and often are. If this is a coursework exercise, then it's necessary to follow the rules set for that coursework and it's pointless asking here.

Comment: Coursework usually entails a broad-brush approach?

Comment: Thank you. BTW, what does 'OP' mean? Is it pronounced oh-pee (individual letters pronounced)? Never heard of it.

Comment: @whippoorwill "OP" is oh-pee. Opening Post (or Opening Poster).

Comment: +1 @EdwinAshworth I agree. Publishers have their own house styles. If the house style dictates song titles in quotes and album titles italicized, then that is what the OP must use. However, the house styles can differ according to country, publisher, academic institution, fashion etc

Answer (score 2):

It looks funny, but I believe that's correct. Putting the possessive inside the quotes is the only alternative, and that would be wrong.